# DispatchTimer not firing in service

Tags: c#, service

I have a windows service implemented in C#. The service watches a number of directories for a file to be saved. However to make it more robust I am trying to get it to check the folders after a period of time.

The inner class called a Watcher initialises both the fileSystemWatcher and DispatchTimer.

```
public class Watcher
{
    FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = null;

    public delegate void TimerInvokedHandler(object sender);
    public event TimerInvokedHandler TimerInvoked;

    public DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; }

    public int TimerMinutes { get; set; }

    public Watcher()
    {

    }

    public Watcher(String directory, String filter, String dap)
    {
        this.DAP            = dap;
        this.Directory      = directory;
        this.Filter         = filter;
    }

    public Boolean EnableRaisingTimerEvents
    {
        get { return this.Timer.IsEnabled;  }
        set
        {
            this.Timer.IsEnabled = value;
            if (value)
            {
                this.Timer.Start();
                Log("Timer Started");
            }
            else
            {
                this.Timer.Stop();
                Log("Timer Stopped");
            }

        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopWatch();
        TimerInvoked?.Invoke(sender);
    }

    public void StartWatch()
    {
        if (fileSystemWatcher == null)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fileSystemWatcher.Filter = Filter;
            fileSystemWatcher.Path = Directory;

            fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
            fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;

            fileSystemWatcher.Error += FileSystemWatcher_Error;
        } 

        if (this.Timer == null)
        {
            Log("Initialising Timer");

            this.Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            this.Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, this.TimerMinutes, 0);
            this.Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }

        this.EnableRaisingFileSystemsEvents = true;
        this.EnableRaisingTimerEvents = true;

        Log(String.Format("Watching Directory {0}", Directory));
    }

    // stops timer and file system events
    public void StopWatch()
    {
        if (fileSystemWatcher != null) 
            EnableRaisingFileSystemsEvents = false;

        if (Timer != null)
        {
            EnableRaisingTimerEvents = false;
        }

        Log(String.Format("Watching {0} Switched Off", this.Directory));
    }


    private void Log ( String Message )
    {
        LogEvent?.Invoke(this, Message);
    }

}
```

The outer class creates a list of these watchers, this is based on ServiceBase, as in it is a service and so only ends when it gets a stopped within the Windows Service Manager

```
                foreach (nhs_acquisition_profile pfl in p)
                {
                    Watcher w = null;
                    String filePattern = String.Empty;

                    try
                    {

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("Attempting to set-up watcher on {0} for DAP {1}",pfl.dap_file_location,pfl.dap_name));

                        if (pfl.dap_acquisition_method_loca.ToLower() == "xml") w = new Watcher(pfl.dap_file_location, "*.xml", pfl.dap_name);
                        else w = new Watcher(pfl.dap_file_location, "*.*", pfl.dap_name);

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Initialising Event Handlers");
                        // initialise event handlers
                        w.FileCreated   += W_FileCreated;
                        w.FileRenamed   += W_FileRenamed;
                        w.TimerInvoked  += W_TimerInvoked;
                        w.LogEvent      += W_LogEvent;
                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Event Handlers initialised");

                        // dispatch timer

                        w.TimerMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(Properties.Settings.Default.TimerDelay);

                        w.StartWatch();

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Watch started....Adding to Watcher List");

                        // add the watcher to the list of watchers
                        FileWatcherList.Add(w);

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry("Added to list of file watchers");

                        profileWatcherLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("Watching {0} for files matching *.* for DAP {1}",pfl.dap_file_location,pfl.dap_name));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
```

The variable FileWatcherList is a field of the ProfileWatcher class which forms the service as a whole.

What I am finding is that the DispatchTimer Tick event never happens. I'm reasonable certain that this is not an instance of the DispatchTimer being disposed of before the Tick, but can't see why it is not firing.

Comment: Does your program have WPF UI? DispatcherTimer only works if there is a UI Dispatcher. You probably should use System.Threading.Timer instead.

Comment: Dmitri Baliev - that might be it. This is a service so it does not have an interface let alone one written in WPF!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dmitri is correct, I should have been using a Timer and not a DispatchTimer. Once I moved to that it worked fine.